# How to assign table space while creating auto partition

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table called EMPLOYEE_DATA which has columns Name char,Joining DATE and it is range partitioned on Joining on weekly basis i.e for every 7 days a new will be created automatically and its TABLE SPACE is TBS1.

Now i have huge amount data on a table and my table space got almost full.
My requirement is from now on wards what ever the partition create automatically on table, that partition should store in another table space i.e TBS2.
please suggest can i do that?

Comment: Just add more datafiles to the existing tablespace. Why would you want to create different tablespace?

Comment: I cannot add extra data files to existing table space. I want the partition to be created on new table space only.